# Incomplete Normal map from bake

Tags: normal-map

[image: Incomplete normal map]

Hello, I've been trying create a normal map of muscle anatomy for an asset I bought. I had copied my lower poly (5000) man asset, subdivided to (1 000 000) and sculpted on the Muscle anatomy. However when it comes to bake, the normal map created only covers part of the characters body.
both models are UV unwrapped (I unwrapped lower poly one and copied it for the higher poly).
I am using cycles but no amount of tweaking the ray distance or using a cage allows the whole map to be made (unless I'm missing something)

Sculpt
[image: Sculpt]

Low poly topography and UV
[image: low poly topography]

How the high(red) and low poly overlap
[image: How the high(red) and low poly overlap]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for hours and followed all the tutorials I can find to no avail.

Comment: The third picture shows you have some faces which covers the whole UV and it's bad. You can also have wrong face normals and multiple materials what can cause these artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I'm not sure how my unwrapping had a square that covered it, but once I edited the UV to scale the giant square into a tiny one and put it somewhere not overlapping it worked resulting on a complete normal map.